# Rectangle is not being drawn

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to make a drawing program in WPF but I ran into some problems.
I can succesfully draw lines (yeeey) but I also want the ability to fill out space (my method is stacking alot of recntagles with the same starting point).
but when I switch my radiobutton from "line" to "fill" it doesnt draw anything.

-- drawing (boolean) is used to create the starting point of filling

Code

```
private void cnvs_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && linemode.IsChecked == true)
        {
            Line line = new Line();
            drawing = true;
            line.Stroke = currentbrush;
            line.X1 = currentPoint.X - 9;
            line.Y1 = currentPoint.Y - 9;
            line.X2 = e.GetPosition(this).X - 9;
            line.Y2 = e.GetPosition(this).Y - 9;
            currentPoint = e.GetPosition(this);
            cnvs.Children.Add(line);
        } else if (cnvs.IsFocused == true)
        {
            if (!drawing) rectbeggining = e.GetPosition(this);
            drawing = true;
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
            rect.Stroke = currentbrush;
            rect.StrokeThickness = 1;
            rect.Height = (Math.Abs(e.GetPosition(this).Y) - Math.Abs(rectbeggining.Y));
            rect.Width = (rectbeggining.X - e.GetPosition(this).X);
            Canvas.SetLeft(rect, e.GetPosition(this).X);
            Canvas.SetTop(rect, Math.Abs(e.GetPosition(this).Y));
            cnvs.Children.Add(rect);
        }
        if(e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Released) drawing = false;
    }
```

Xaml

```
<Grid>    
    <Border Name="CanvasBorder" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Margin="8,8,207,9"/>    
    <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="972" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1493" MouseDown="Canvas_MouseDown" MouseMove="cnvs_MouseMove" Name="cnvs">    
        <Canvas.Background>    
            <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0"/>    
        </Canvas.Background>    
    </Canvas>    
    <ComboBox Name="selectcolor" Margin="1510,10,10,945" SelectedItem="Black" SelectionChanged="selectcolor_SelectionChanged" SelectedIndex="7">    
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>    
            <DataTemplate>    
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">    
                    <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Name}" Width="16" Height="16" Margin="0,2,5,2" />    
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />    
                </StackPanel>    
            </DataTemplate>    
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>    
    </ComboBox>    
    <Button Content="Reset" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1510,939,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="192" Click="Button_Click" Height="44"/>
    <RadioButton GroupName="selectedMode" Name="linemode" Content="Line" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1510,232,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsChecked="True"/>    
    <RadioButton GroupName="selectedMode" Name="fillmode" Content="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1510,247,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label Content="Mode:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1510,206,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>    
</Grid>
```

Comment: [WPF Draw Filled Rectangle](https://www.google.ca/search?q=wpf+draw+filled+rectangle&oq=wpf+draw+fill&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.6823j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: You need to modify the existing rectangle, not create a new one each `MouseMove` event. Same with Lines, you are creating tons of lines on top of each other each time the event fires.

Comment: Actually, it was intended with the lines. Its supposed to be like pen you know ? But about that rectangle, can I somehow just use 2 points to create one and later change only one point ? (to make it like you said, only resize one) I know I could change the size somehow but that would allow me to only go the same direction wouldnt it ?

Answer (score -1):

I'm working on the map editor for generalstaff at the moment. You pick between line or area types of terrain, draw and when you finish a stroke it's processed.
Unless I've misunderstood your purpose that sounds pretty much like you're doing.

I essentially have an inkcanvas on top of a canvas.
It's rather more complicated than that.  I bind viewmodels to an itemscontrol which has a canvas as it's itemspresenter and template data into the pieces of terrain.

I can bore at length on this stuff.

I use inkcanvas because it gives you smoother results than drawing directly on a canvas. I started off using a canvas like that but you get jiggly bits..

The strokeschanged event is used to tell when a stroke on the inkcanvas has finished.
Each stroke has a styluspointcollection StylusPoints and you can iterate through that to get the points.

Once you have the points, you can build a polygon.
I do that by templating and I bind the Points property of a Polygon to a Pointcollection from a viewmodel.
A polygon has a Fill property which you can set or bind to a solidcolorbrush.
And in that way you can draw any shape you like, then fill it with one colour.